# Question with complex type definitions c++

Tags: c++, winapi

So I saw this on a code snippet online:

```cpp
typedef LRESULT(CALLBACK* WNDPROC)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

What I want to know here is structure-wise.

What does this mean?

I read the [msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/typedef-declarations?view=vs-2019) documentation for typedefs but I still can't figure out what this does here, so I know it wants to give a synonym for `LRESULT` but what does the `(CALLBACK* WNDPROC)` do here, does it Mean name `f_EndScene` as a pointer to a `CALLBACK` which takes `(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)` parameters is a synonym for an LRESULT?

I really can't wrap my head around this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WNDPROC` is the name of the `typedef`. I'll admit that knowing this is a bit of an art. The rule is basically that the name of a `typedef`/variable is actually the *innermost* thing in the declaration. Starting at the name, move right when you can and left when you must, respecting parentheses (the spiral rule). The declaration actually reads:

Declare the type alias `WNDPROC` to be pointer to `CALLBACK` function taking arguments `HWND`, `UINT`, `WPARAM`, and `LPARAM` returning `LRESULT`.

The spiral rule basically comes from nesting. Starting from the simplest typedef possible and repeatedly replacing the place where the actual typedef name goes with the "missing" bit of the tree:

```
typedef LRESULT WNDPROC; // WNDPROC = LRESULT
typedef LRESULT WNDPROC(...); // WNDPROC = function taking (...) returning LRESULT
typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK WNDPROC)(...); // WNDPROC = CALLBACK function taking (...) returning LRESULT
typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK *WNDPROC)(...); // WNDPROC = pointer to CALLBACK function taking (...) returning LRESULT
```

Answer (score 2):

This `typedef` declares `WNDPROC` type, it is a pointer to a function type.

All it fits standard C and C++, except `CALLBACK`. `CALLBACK` is a macro that expands to `__stdcall` which is one of x86 calling conventions. (On x64 you can ignore `__stdcall`, there's (mostly) only one calling convetnion on x64)

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I don't understand, so you are saying that `WNDPROC` is a pointer to a `long __stdcall function` that takes the parameters specified?

Comment: so it is the same as `LRESULT CALLBACK* WNDPROC(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)`? @AlexGuteniev

Comment: No, that's `WNDPROC` = function taking ... returning pointer to `CALLBACK LRESULT`, which is nonsense

Comment: Yes, it is a pointer to such function. No it is not `LRESULT CALLBACK* WNDPROC(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)` - this declaration would be a function returning `LRESULT CALLBACK*`. And that's why there are parentheses around `(CALLBACK* WNDPROC)`